how to add/pass .env file using github action in firebase hosting
i want to add or run .env file in firebase using github action
here is what i did
.github/workflows/firebase-hosting-merge.yml
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - run: npm ci && npm run build

      - name: Load environment variables from .env file
        run: |
          if [ -f .env ]; then
            export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)
          fi
          cat .env
          
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          firebaseServiceAccount: ${{
            secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TEST_GOOGLE_PAGE }}
          channelId: live
          projectId: test-google-page
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          
     ### I USE THIS ALSO BUT ABOVE & BELOW ARE SAME COMMAND ###
      # - name: Deploy to Firebase
      #   env:
      #     VARIABLE: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_GOVERNANCE_LANDING_PAGE }}
      #   run: firebase deploy --only hosting

      ### Optional    
      # - name: Set environment variables
      #   run: |
      #     echo "VUE_APP_ADMIN_ROLE=${{ secrets.VUE_APP_ADMIN_ROLE }}" >> .env
      #     echo "VUE_APP_API_URL=${{ secrets.VUE_APP_API_URL }}" >> .env
      #     cat .env

This is repo of github code
enter image description here

I have added .env in the root directory of github repo
Everything is working fine even .env file is reading from above action but when i dont know whether its reading .env file or not and deployed into firebase account

Here is output where i need to show .env values reflected or not
enter image description here so its not reflecting the values which im looking
cat .env
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://test.devops.com:3002/api/v1/xxxxxxx/xxxx


actually values it need to show :- http://test.devops.com:3002/api/v1/xxxxxxx/xxxx
current values showing :- http://localhost:3002/api/v1/xxxxxxx/xxxx

even i read this docs
5. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#env-variables
But dont understand how to do
but in code of repo under subfolder i see this line
const apiEndpoint = process.env.SECURITY_AI_URL || "http://localhost:3002";

and i cannot change any code under repo of github because its client repo
please tell me what should i do to solve .env

What happens if you instead put SECURITY_AI_URL=http://test.devops.com:3002 in your .env file instead of VUE_APP_API_URL? Do you see any change? Where is the const apiEndpoint line? In a folder under src or public? Have you tried setting SECURITY_AI_URL before running the build command? (at the moment .env is loaded after the build in the above YAML)

yes const apiEndpoint is under src/api/axios-client.ts and i dont know where do i need to set .env file after build or before build if above is correct then let me know otherwise i will change it and regarding SECURITY_AI_URL instead of SECURITY_AI_URL that i need to check
